# capture column pattern frequency

Tags: r, dplyr, transform, frequency, reshape2

I have a dataset like this below

```
Id        A      B       C
10        1      0       1
11        1      0       1
12        1      1       0
13        1      0       0
14        0      1       1
```

I am trying to count the column patterns like this below.

```
 Pattern         Count
 A, C            2
 A, B            1
 A               1
 B, C            1
```

Not sure where to start, any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: @Ty Voss do you need the sum of these columns based on ID

Comment: You tagged this with `dplyr`, so you could probably also do `df %>% gather(variable, value, -Id) %>% group_by(Id) %>% summarise(res = toString(variable[value == 1])) %>% count(res)`

Comment: @Arunkumarmahesh, Arun,  id is irrelevant here. Good question tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting by "reversing" the tabulation of the data in the two separate vectors:

```
w = which(dat[-1] == 1L, TRUE)
```

we could use

```
table(tapply(names(dat)[-1][w[, "col"]], w[, "row"], paste, collapse = ", "))
#
#   A A, B A, C B, C 
#   1    1    2    1
```

If the result is not needed only for formatting purposes, to avoid unnecessary `paste`/`strsplit`, an alternative -among many- is:

```
pats = split(names(dat)[-1][w[, "col"]], w[, "row"])
upats = unique(pats)
data.frame(pat = upats, n = tabulate(match(pats, upats)))
#   pat n
#1 A, C 2
#3 A, B 1
#4    A 1
#5 B, C 1
```

Comment: this worked perfect. , i used `as.data.frame` and it didnt have to use those last three split, unique etc..

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have to group per ID then simply,

```
table(apply(df[-1], 1, function(i) paste(names(i[i == 1]), collapse = ',')))

#  A A,B A,C B,C 
#  1   1   2   1
```

Comment: You could probably improve this a bit by converting to a logical matrix outside of `apply`, something like `apply(df[-1] == 1, 1, function(i) toString(names(i[i])))`

Answer (score 2):

We can try with

```
table(gsub(",*N|N,*", "", chartr('0123', 'NABC', 
         do.call(paste, c(df1[-1] * col(df1[-1]), sep=",")))))

#  A A,B A,C B,C 
#  1   1   2   1
```

As @DavidArenburg mentioned, the `old/new` in `chartr` can be made automatic with

```
cols <- paste(c("N", names(df1[-1])), collapse = "") 
indx <- paste(seq(nchar(cols)) - 1, collapse = "")
table(gsub(",*N|N,*", "", chartr(indx, cols, 
      do.call(paste, c(df1[-1] * col(df1[-1]), sep=",")))))
```

Comment: This is very nice, though not so general, maybe use something like `cols <- paste(c("N", names(df[-1])), collapse = "") ; indx <- paste(seq(nchar(cols)) - 1, collapse = "")` within `chartr` instead just '0123' and 'NABC'